# How to implement this functionality allowing a user to login using different Sites Credentials?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

i need similar functionality as its was implemented in  StackOverflow.com  means , allowing a user to login from either using yahoo , Google , FaceBook -- etc .

Please let me know how can we implement such a functinality in our web site that allows users to login using differnet implementors ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement OpenId. See this general [overview](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364125/Using-OpenID) to get the idea how it works, later go to  more practical [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-openid/index.html?ca=drs-).